# How to properly deal with Correlation IDs?

Tags: microservices

I have just been reading up on logging in a microservice architecture and there seems to be this concept of Correlation ID, which is basically passed along to each  microservice. This Correlation ID can be useful for logging - you can trace requests across microservices just by searching the Correlation ID.

My question is, how is this usually implemented? Where is this Correlation ID generated? Do you generate some sort of UUID on the Frontend, and pass it along via the X-REQUEST-ID HTTP header?

My second question is: when you receive this Correlation ID in the server, how do you make it accessible to all the functions in the server?

Suppose your server had something like this:

```
requestHandler(httpRequest) {
    correlationId = httpRequest.header.get(X-REQUEST-ID)
    ...
    function2()
}

function2() {
    ...
    function3()
}

function3() {
    ...
    function4()
}

function4() {
    ...
}
```

Suppose I wanted to log something in function4() (assume that I want the log to include the Correlation ID as well), do I really have to pass the Correlation ID all the way down from requestHandler() to function4()? Or is there a better approach?

My first thought would be to have some sort of in-memory key-value DB where you can store the Correlation ID as a value, but what would be the key?

Comment: What actual language would be used in your microservice(s) ?

Comment: In Golang, I'm guessing this RequestID would be attached to the Context and the context would be passed into all the functions. But how would you do this in perhaps a python Flask microservice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes its a kind of UUID only, whenever frontend sends the request to API Gateway or orchestration layer, then this UUID is generated and added to the subsequent calls to be made to each of the microservices to be traced.

Hence if you are giving synchronous calls or asynchronous calls via some messaging broker, this is something that you are supposed to embed in the header always and the called function will put this into logging at the beginning only, using this correlationID later you can intercept the call flow in your logging client.

Comment: Ah I see, thanks. Any suggestions with regards to the second question?

Comment: yeah, I added info pertaining to that also. You have to add the CorrID in every call, and please do mark it useful if it appears to be

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand, so would you pass the Correlation ID all the way down from the requestHandler() function to function4()?

Comment: Are you working on kubernetes based environements ? if yes, then please check for Jaeger, it is a utility that takes care of distributed tracing

Comment: But wouldn't code become very ugly when you start passing the UUID as a parameter to all functions (and all their ancestors) that need logging? I'm assuming most functions would require logging, and you would have to pass the UUID to every single function in your application - which feels really ugly.

Comment: correct for this purpose, the environments have plugins like Jaeger, Java based environments have Zipkins too, this is something like a middleware that may be existing in Nodejs based frameworks too ( but the implementation that we did for nodeJS was this way only as I cited above )